# Offsetting successive frames

Tags: frames

In my `init.el` I have the below setting for the initial frame position:

```
(setq default-frame-alist
    '((top . 80) (left . 300) (width . 85) (height . 45)))
```

When I open a file in a new frame, it overlaps the previous frame.

How do I set the position of the new frame to be, for example, `x` width and `y` height from the previous frame?

This is so that the new frame will not overlap with the previous frame and all open frames (windows) will be clearly visible.

Comment: Put your *initial* parameters in `initial-frame-alist`, and then put different values in `default-frame-alist`.  The first frame created at startup will use the former, and then all others will use the latter.

Comment: @Drew: yup, you're right.  Reading comprehension fail on my part.

Comment: @Dan, I did try your suggestion as well. What I did was have some values in `initial-frame-alist` and different (offset) values in `default-frame-alist`. The first emacs frame and next frame (on doing `C-x 5 2` once) are offset, but doing `C-x 5 2` again makes the second and third frame overlap, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Define a function that you use to create the frame, which does what you want with respect to positioning.
2. Define whatever commands you want that make use of that function. For example, define a command that you use in place of `find-file-other-frame` (`C-x 5 f`), define a command that you use in place of `make-frame-command` (`C-x 5 2`).

The function for #1 just calls `make-frame`, passing the `top` and `left` values you want, in the optional second arg, `PARAMETERS`.

Presumably, you want those `top` and `left` values to be calculated from their values in the currently `selected-frame`.

For example:

```lisp
(defun make-offset-frame (&optional x y)
  "..."
  (let* ((params  (frame-parameters))
         (ctop    (or (cdr (assoc 'top params))   0))
         (cleft   (or (cdr (assoc 'left params))  0)))
    (setq x  (or x  30)
          y  (or y  30))
    (make-frame (append `((top . ,(+ ctop y)) (left . ,(+ cleft x)))
                        default-frame-alist))))


(defun my-make-frame-command (&optional x y)
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (make-offset-frame x y))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 5 2") 'my-make-frame-command)
```

Comment: Doing `C-x 5 2` does create a new frames offset from the previous frame, but their size is **not** 80 by 45. Is there a way I could have the new frames the same size of the initial frame?

Comment: Updated to use `default-frame-alist` for the other parameters, besides `left` and `top`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tiling window manager such as [i3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I3_(window_manager)) or [StumpWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StumpWM).

Comment: I think OP wanted an Emacs-based solution that does not require the use of a different window manager.

Comment: Of course you may be right, @Dan. No way of knowing unless/until Saurabh says.